# Power Suppy for Modem Router from 12V Car battery

Tags: power-supply, wifi

How i can operate my modem router (KW58283 300M 11N ADSL2+ Modem Router) on 12V car battery.
The Modm router is rated as 12V ,1A.
I have this battery.
[Force battey http://www.forcebatteries.com.pk/res/gallries/lgallery59536535.jpg](http://www.forcebatteries.com.pk/res/gallries/lgallery59536535.jpg)

The complete router information are here:

> http://www.kasdanet.com/ENHCSZ/pro_view-20.html

can i connect it directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you should be able to.
The battery supplies a couple of volts more than you need, but the regulators in the modem should be able to handle it, though it will get warmer since it has to regulate a higher voltage.  It may also run closer to the limits of some parts (capacitors and such in the power supply.)

If you'd rather be safe than sorry, you could get a small DC/DC switching power supply that puts out a regulated 12Volts from the battery voltage.  That way, your modem gets the 12V it likes, and any extra heat is generated outside of the modem housing.

---

In response to comment:

I would use a small DC to DC converter module.  I find them available at various places on the internet.

[This is an example of what you need.](http://www.ebay.de/itm/150W-DC-DC-Boost-Converter-10-32V-to-12-35V-6A-Step-Up-Adjustable-Power-Supply-/261177824309?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item3ccf695435)  I am not recommending that you buy that one from that dealer.  That is an example only.  I expect you can find better examples with better prices or more reliable dealers or what have you.

Comment: What should be safe and easy way for me?

Answer (score -2):

No you can't connect it directly. Get your self a power inverter. You can get a cheap one at any auto parts store, typically the quality is only so so, but you really don't need anything that fancy for your application. The converter connects to the battery typically via alligator clips, the converter will have a home style(110 volt a/c) plug, just plug the router into it and you should be good to go. Just curious but how are you planning on charging the battery? The inverter will kill the battery eventually, you will be lucky to get a couple days out of it.

Comment: I am charging the 12V battery through a Solar Cell. Here in my country 2 hr Ac is available and 1 hr not. I want not to use Ac for router. I want to connect it to battery. Will a 12V voltage regulator help me? I fear the thing that burn devices is current,, what should i do now??

Comment: Why do you need an inverter to run a 12V modem off a 12V battery?

Comment: Because AC is not available 24hr in my country. i have a 12V car battery, and a Solar panel which produce 100V.